# A For loop with embedded if statement to update a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am a newcomer to python. I want to implement a "For" loop on the elements of a dataframe, with an embedded "if" statement.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Dataframes
x = pd.DataFrame([1,-2,3])
y = pd.DataFrame()

for i in x.iterrows():
    for j in x.iteritems():
        if x>0:
            y = x*2
        else:
            y = 0
```

With the previous loop, I want to go through each item in the x dataframe and generate a new dataframe y based on the condition in the "if" statement. When I run the code, I get the following error message.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `if j>0`?

Comment: Could you add an example of expected output?

Comment: If your data is one dimensional, as in your example, consider using a series instead.

Comment: @DanielRoseman when I do as you suggested, I get the error TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: @zipa The expected output would be a populated "y" dataframe with the same dimension as the "x" dataframe, but with values 2, 0, 6.

Comment: @9769953 This is but an example. In fact I have much bigger dataframes with more columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pandas is best avoid loops if exist vectorized solution:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([1,-2,3], columns=['a'])

y = pd.DataFrame(np.where(x['a'] > 0, x['a'] * 2, 0), columns=['b'])
print (y)
   b
0  2
1  0
2  6
```

**Explanation**:

First compare column by value for boolean mask:

```
print (x['a'] > 0)
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Then use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set values by conditions:

```
print (np.where(x['a'] > 0, x['a'] * 2, 0))
[2 0 6]
```

And last use `DataFrame` constructor or create new column:

```
x['new'] = np.where(x['a'] > 0, x['a'] * 2, 0)
print (x)
   a  new
0  1    2
1 -2    0
2  3    6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
y = (x[(x > 0)]*2).fillna(0)
```